# EMPTY? expected input to be a string or list but got the TRUE/FALSE false instead

Tags: netlogo

I used "empty?" in many parts of the code and I don't understand the error in which part it refers exactly. I write here a part of code where I used 'empty?'. I don't understand what is wrong.

```
""ask shuttles [
     ifelse empty? onlyNodes = TRUE
    [ calc-short-shuttles
      ;get the original lists back
      set place last onlyNodes
      ;change the location (lew location is the prior destination)
      if place = node 98 [
        set destination "MilanoCentrale1"
      ]
      if place = node 191 [
        set destination "InnovationCampus1"
      ]
      if place = node 192 [
        set destination "InnovationCampus2"
      ]
      if place = node 219 [
        set destination "MilanoLinate1"
      ]
      calc-short-shuttles
      ;new shortest path for the way back
    ]""
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order om which Netlogo tries to execute the different procedures is the problem here. If I would write it down using brackets, Netlogo is trying to:
`(ifelse (empty? (onlyNodes = TRUE)))`

You can introduce brackets of yourself into your code when you are not sure in which order Netlogo would execute the procedure. This allows you to make sure that `empty?` is executed before `= TRUE`: `ifelse (empty? onlyNodes) = TRUE`

For this specific case, none of this actually matters.`ifelse` requires an input that is either TRUE or FALSE. `= TRUE` generates an output that is either TRUE or FALSE but so does `empty?`, so `=TRUE` is redundant.

`ifelse empty? onlyNodes [<command1>][<command2>]`